# How to set a PNG as a MAP?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, png

I'm doing some programming in WPF. My goal is creat a TRPG(Text-RPG), so a map is definitely needed.

I got a PNG picture that can be separated in 5×5.

I want to separate this PNG, the add some Code on these little squares, for example, the picture's code in left bottom corner is (0, 0). 
(I'll add functions to make sure I'll be able to travel on this MAP later.)

Now I want to figure out how can I separate the PNG?

Then add it in my code? 
Creat a new .cs? .edmx?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend taking a step back and concisely identify exactly how you plan to represent geographic area in your application.

If you are planning to have an NxM grid to display geographic area of the "map" in your app, you might want to instead just draw the map's "image" on the background of your window.  You can then overlay transparent controls on top of the actual map (such as labels for the individual grid cells).

Fortunately, WPF provides a very applicable layout mechanism for you to do this, a *Grid*.

See http://wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dynamic bitmap array. and define all of the bitmaps and just run a foreach loop to draw them.

```
Bitmap[] bitmapArray = new Bitmap[width * height]; //the size of your map

for(int i = 0; i <= bitmapArray.Length - 1; i++)
{
    //Define the bitmaps here
}

foreach(Bitmap b in bitmapArray)
{
    //Drawing Code
}
```